# Inject environment and run powershell script in Windows Base Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: powershell, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I use pipelines in Jenkins on Linux Base to set environment variables and execute shell scripts

But now I ’m going to use windows base Jenkins to do the same thing
The following is my original pipeline script

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    environment {
    productName="CentOS"
    projectName="Test1"
    }
    stages {
        stage('run shell script') {
            steps {
                sh ('/var/lib/jenkins/tools/runShell.sh')

            }
        }
  }
}
```

powershell script in windows base path:
E:\Jenkins\Scan\RunScript.ps1

how can I change to the windows variable and execute the powershell script?

Comment: in steps, something like 
powershell "E:\Jenkins\Scan\RunScript.ps1" or
powershell " & E:\Jenkins\Scan\RunScript.ps1"
& --> Call operator

agent you will need to define.

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/